# How can I change the button's background image twice in MouseLeftButtonDown event?

Tags: wpf, button, background-image, mouseleftbuttondown

I write the following event handler in `MainWindow.xaml.cs`. I want to achieve such an effect，when the business logic is running the runbutton's background image switches to `powerOnOff1.png`, when the business logic is finished the background image switches back to `powerOnOff0.png`.

```
    private void Run_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
            {
                //set run button background image to powerOnOff1.png indicates business logic is going to run.
                BitmapImage ima0 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("picture/powerOnOff1.png", UriKind.Relative));             
                image.Source = ima0;

                //business logic
                ...... 

                //restore Runbutton background image to powerOnOff0.png indicates business logic is finished.
                BitmapImage ima1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri("picture/powerOnOff0.png", UriKind.Relative));
                image.Source = ima1;  
            }
```

Above codes doesn't work. It always show `powerOnOff0.png` background image. Does it require multi-threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does it require multithreading?

Yes. You need execute the business logic on a background thread. The easiest way to do this would be to start a new task and await it:

```
private async void Run_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //set run button background image to powerOnOff1.png indicates business logic is going to run.
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("picture/powerOnOff1.png", UriKind.Relative));

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //business logic here
    });

    //restore Runbutton background image to powerOnOff0.png indicates business logic is finished.
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("picture/powerOnOff0.png", UriKind.Relative));
}
```